# Unable to Run bash script of remote Linux host using powershell in GitHub actions

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, ssh, github-actions

I have a bash script `check_disk_space.sh` to check and error exit if disk space for a given mount on a Linux Centos 7 host is less than the threshold(30GB for example).

check_disk_space.sh has 3 input parameters

1. `${{ inputs.mount_points }}` which could be a comma-separated mount point like `/tmp,/etc`
2. `${{ inputs.min_free_space }}` which is the threshold below which free disk space should error and exit.
3. `"$eachhost"` which is each host obtained from the comma-separated list `hosts` where the script(`check_disk_space.sh`) runs and checks for free space.

This is running fine using Github Linux runners as below.

```
  steps:

    - name: Check Disk Space on Remote Hosts
      shell: bash

      run: |

        cd "${{ github.workspace }}/DevOps/scripts"

        IFS=',' read -ra remhosts <<< "${{ inputs.remote_hosts }}"

        for eachhost in "${remhosts[@]}"; do
          ssh -q -t user@"$eachhost" "bash -s" -- < ./check_disk_space.sh "${{ inputs.mount_points }}" "${{ inputs.min_free_space }}" "$eachhost"
        done
```

This works fine however, I now wish to use a Windows runner due to policy constraints.

I tried the below by hard coding the values, but I get an error in doing so.

```
name: Attempt2 Check Disk Space on Remote Hosts

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  check_disk_space:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Check Disk Space on Remote Hosts
        shell: powershell

        run: |
          $remoteHosts = "80.240.24.193,80.240.24.194".Split(",")
          $mountPoints = "/tmp"
          $minFreeSpace = "5"
          $user = "root"

          cd $env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE

          $scriptcode = Get-Content -Raw -Path ./check_disk_space.sh

          foreach ($eachhost in $remoteHosts) {
            $sshCommand = "ssh -q -t $user@$eachhost `"bash -s`" --"

            $command = @"
            $scriptcode
           ./check_disk_space.sh "$mountPoints" "$minFreeSpace" "$eachhost"
           "@

            $finalCommand = ($sshCommand + " `"$(echo $command)`"").Trim()
            Write-Output $finalCommand
            Invoke-Expression $finalCommand
          }
```

Error:

```
Run $remoteHosts = "80.240.24.193,80.240.24.194".Split(",")
At D:\a\_temp\06b226b4-60d8-40ca-82d2-f8f76669f636.ps1:17 char:2
+  "@
+  ~~
White space is not allowed before the string terminator.
At D:\a\_temp\06b226b4-60d8-40ca-82d2-f8f76669f636.ps1:11 char:37
+ foreach ($eachhost in $remoteHosts) {
+                                     ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WhitespaceBeforeHereStringFooter
```

Thus, my attempt to run `check_disk_space.sh` using PowerShell on a remote linux host fails for which I got no clue why.

Sample run with error here: https://github.com/knowyrtech/invokebashfrompowershell/actions/runs/5894294098/job/15987641430

I tried a different approach which was resolved by the accepted answer but unable to use it to execute `check_disk_space.sh` script of remote Linux there too: [Unable to use powershell's sshArgs to invoke a simple ssh command on remote linux host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76910754/unable-to-use-powershells-sshargs-to-invoke-a-simple-ssh-command-on-remote-linu)

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `$host` variable in PowerShell and you are probably not aware of that it is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#host) in PowerShell. Replace it by whatever you *really* want.

Concerning your error message: You are passing two strings to `Invoke-Expression`, but this cmdlet expects only one string. Either adjust your quoting or use another approach like direct invocation or `Start-Process`.

Comment: i will implement your suggestion  and update here after 9 hrs

Comment: Upon i suggestion I m getting a different error and am still unable to achieve the purpose of this thread i.e execute bash script on remote Linux host using PowerShell and passing arguments

Comment: i updated the original post with the suggested changes made and the error. Kindly suggest @stackprotector

Comment: @Ashar Please stop editing your question to address new problems. Post a new question instead. Your edit invalidates my answer.

Comment: i understand that your answer addresses the exception I posted initially but it does not get me achieve the purpose for this post of getting to run a bash script on remote host using PowerShell. In doing so I have encounter several different errors everytime I try something different to get it to work. In posting the error does not imply I m looking to overcome that error but trying to achieve the functionality which was mentioned without edits. Please let me know if u want me to post again with the current details and close this thread?

Comment: I suggest you roll back your edit and post a new question. Try to focus on one problem only. While doing so, you will most probably solve the problems by yourself. Be aware, that you are currently facing simple PowerShell problems that have nothing to do with GitLab CI. So reduce your code to the PowerShell part. Reduce it even more to a [MRE].  Also while your main goal is to "get everything working", this is not what these Q&As are about. Here on SO, only focussed (on one single problem!) and concise questions are allowed.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332863/11942268) is the community consensus on "chameleon questions" btw.

Comment: Although i was looking for a solution to be able to execute a bash script on target Linux 
 using PowerShell your answer did help overcome the error I faced. I Accepted the answer. Thank you @stackprotector